# add your own entry to a select list

Tags: drop-down-list, select

is there a userfriendly way of adding an entry to a selectlist with predefined options? besides being able of selecting a value from a select list i want the option to add a value of my own but am not sure how this would work/look. I know it's possible to foresee a free text field within the select list but what is the behaviour after i enter a value in this field.

Personally, I would simply foresee a free inputfield (instead of a select dropdown list) where a user can enter a free text value but where he also has the possibility of selecting from a list of predefined options that shows up when he enters text. Is this generally feasible as validation towards backend? The underlying technology would be Oracle APEX mobile by the way.

Was looking for examples to share but can't seem to find exactly what i need.

thx

Comment: This sort of functionality often used by eCommerce websites when saving the users address - for selecting quicker the next time. Check out some checkout sections of sites and see how they do it. Your question also sounds like you want the workflow for this, which is not really a UX question.

Comment: Alright i'll look out for it, thx. I'm looking for some kind of task flow here so why would it not be a UX question? It's related to the user experience best practices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard way of solving this is autocomplete. For instance, here is how it works in Jira.

User starts editing a field. There are options to accept/cancel the input:

[image]

User may click the down arrow and see a list of existing items:

[image]

Or they can start typing in the field and then it offers a list to autocomplete:

[image]

Finally, user may add their own value:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what i had in mind! I found that JIRA really has a lot of useful ux patterns. On the other hand, it seems that APEX does not use this pattern out of the box. It allows to select a value from the list but when you want to add a new value, you should click a separate button which brings up a dialog box. After filling in a value it inserts it in the lis. At least that's what our developer tells me.

Answer (score 1):

On an Apex implementation (not
mobile) we are currently developing, we use the [Select2 jquery plugin](https://select2.github.io) on the front-end.

This awesome extended select-box allows for all kinds of customized implementations, including autocomplete, multi-select, and adding new entries.

I can really recommend looking at Select2.

Comment: Hi wintvelt, thx! I did indeed find about this jquery plugin but it did not directly give me what i looked for. I did find some other useful functionalities i used in my prototype though ;)